# Euchre - Calling a a renege after the hand is closed before the next deal?

Tags: euchre

Can you call a renege after the hand is closed before the next deal??

Answer (score 1):

Once the hand is closed the renege is much harder to verify, once the cards played that round have been returned to the deck. A renege should be called immediately when it is noticed. Taken tricks should be kept separate from each other, organised so the order they were taken is clear, this allows a renege to be verified and not rely on everyone's memory.